# What is $E[x]$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There are $m$ white balls and $n$ black balls in bag. We take out one-by-one each one of the $m+n$ balls. Let $X$ be the random variable denotes the number of white balls before taking out the first black ball. What is $E[X]$?

So the probability:

$$Pr(X=k) = \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{m-i}{n+m-i}$$

So the expectancy may be:

$$E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^m k \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{m-i}{n+m-i}$$

But that's a little hard to evaluate. Is there a better way I am missing?

Comment: $P(X=k)$ should be a product, not a sum.

Comment: Oh right, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the white balls $1$ to $m$. Define the Bernoulli random variable $X_i$ by  $X_i=1$ if white ball $i$ is removed before any black ball, and $X_u=0$ otherwise. Then $X=X_1+\cdots+X_m$ and 
$$E(X)=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_m).$$
To find $E(X_i)$, note that $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how did you get $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: Is that a "No"? :)

Comment: No, it is not a no. Spent the day (and many other days, past and future) moving. Let $W_i$ be white ball $i$. Consider the set of $n+1$ balls consisting of $W_i$ and the $n$ black balls. Since all sequences of balls are equally likely, the probability that $W_i$ is comes before all the blacks is $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Thus $E(X)=\frac{m}{n+1}$.

Comment: You are welcome. This is one of the many examples where finding the distribution function, and then the mean, is quie a bit harder than Indicator random variables.

Answer (score 0):

$${\rm P}(X=k)=\frac{n}{m+n}\prod_{r=0}^{k}\frac{m-r}{m+n-1-r}$$